# How do I only get a part of the response as a string

Tags: python

How can I get only a part of the response I get back in form of a string?

Code:

```
Status1 = r.text
```

Response text:

```
{
 "status" : "DUPLICATE"
}
```

```
Status1 = Status1.replace('"', "")
Status1 = Status1.replace("{", "")
Status1 = Status1.replace("}", "")
```

New response:

```
  status : DUPLICATE
```

but if I put in the follwing code it still does not work/seems to be not the same. How come?

```
A = "status : DUPLICATE"
if A==Status1:
print("True")
```

I only need the word DUPLICATE from the whole response, so is there any way to get only this word so the if statement works?

Comment: Why don't you access that _as JSON_, rather than replacing bits of it yourself?

Comment: hey, thanks for the quick answer, do you have an example how to do such?

Comment: Read the requests docs, literally the first example shows you: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. If you mean how to work with a dictionary once you have it, I'd strongly recommend basic tutorials: https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F.

Answer (score 0):

your response seems to be json formatted, so you should be able to get a python object directly with `r.json`

otherwise do

```
import json
obj = json.loads(r.text)
print obj['status']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just parse the input as json, and it will convert it to a python dictionary:

```
response_json = r.json()

if response_json["status"] == "DUPLICATE"
    print("True")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
 import json
 response_object = json.loads(r.text)
 response_object["status"]
```

[image]